# Hide api_call from end users

Tags: reactjs, api

I have an app written in ReactJs that makes connection to our backend server (python/django).

Whenever I make a call to that server, you can see it in the Network monitor. which means when following the link, you can just copy the data. we don't want that.

[image]

is there any way to hide this in ReactJS?

Comment: No. If you don't want anyone to see the data api returns when directly accessed consider authentification

Answer (score 2):

Security through Obscurity is not a good idea, even if you would be able to hide the debugger, the user could just run it on another electron instance with an attached debugger and export it like that, keeping data the client should not have on the users side is a sign of bad design.

Comment: Could a solution be server-side-rendering my application? I have no knowledge of this but I heard from someone it could be.

Comment: What kind of data does the client send there?

Comment: It's data from users, so objects, arrays, boleans, strings... I get them in JSON form

Comment: So whats the problem with them being visible to he users? The users entered the data, so there shouldnt be any security implications (except if your backend doesnt use https, but that would be a different problem)

Comment: True, I understand what you mean, they see it anyway so what's the point of hiding the api call. Well, there are also other calls and let's say it contains some data that users don't need to see (also just arrays, boleans, ...) could server side rendering be a solution for this?

Comment: Is it bad if the user sees the data? Server side rendering should be used if theres really a reason

Comment: Sadly, It is for my employer.. guess I'll have to find another solution for this